# how to offset a CSS border up and left

Tags: css

We have a Wordpress sidebar designed like this:

[image]

Note the grey border of the large white div is offset up and left (ignore the same effect on the image inside the white div please) - **we want the border offset in our final design**.

I've tried building this with HTML:

```
<aside class="sidebar sidebar-primary widget-area" role="complementary" aria-label="Primary Sidebar" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar" id="genesis-sidebar-primary">
  <h2 class="genesis-sidebar-title screen-reader-text">Primary Sidebar</h2>
  <section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">
    <div class="widget-wrap">
      <div class="textwidget">
        <p><img src="http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/fullytiledpoolssidebarbutton.png" alt="fully tiled pools Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide" title="fully tiled pools Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide"><img src="http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/poolrenovationssidebarbutton.png" alt="pool renovations Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide" title="pool renovations Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide"><img src="http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/PoolTilingSidebarbutton.png" alt="pool tiling Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide" title="pool tiling Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide"><img src="http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/PoolResurfacingSidebarbutton.png" alt="pool resurfacing Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide" title="pool resurfacing Perth, Melbourne, Adelaide"></p>
        <p><a href="/gallery/"><img src="http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/gallery-see-more.png" alt="see our gallery" title="see our gallery"></a></p>
        <ul class="aligncenter" id="social-icons">
          <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/amalfi_interiors/"><img src="/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/instagram.png" alt="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Instagram" title="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Instagram" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/amalfiinteriors/"><img src="/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/facebook.png" alt="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Facebook" title="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Facebook" data-pin-nopin="true"></a></li>
          <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/118279109440835754861/about"><img src="/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/google.png" alt="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Google+" title="Follow Amalfi Interiors on Google+"></a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:steve@doig.com.au"><img src="/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample/images/email.png" alt="Email Amalfi Interiors" title="Email Amalfi Interiors"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

and CSS:

```
.sidebar-primary {
    float: right;
    width: 20.5%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 4px solid #494242;
}
.sidebar-primary section {
    margin: 4% -4% -4% 4%;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 9998;
    opacity: 0.99;
}
```

However, on the [live page](http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/contact/) the inner `section` covers the outer `aside`'s border on the right and the bottom.

I've set a z-index for the `aside` (9999) and `section` (9998), and `position: relative;` but the issue remains.

Help appreciated.

Comment: If remove     margin: 4% -4% -4% 4%; white block fits well.

Comment: Just as a note, when the offset should be the same in all directions, you can use `outline` with `outline-offset`.

Answer (score 10):

Use this principle

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

For your page you need to find setion with `class="text-12"` and update it's code as follows

```
<section id="text-12" class="widget widget_text" style="border:none;padding:0;">
    <div class="clearfix" style="border:none;position:relative;padding:40px;height:100%;">
        <div class="border-set" style="border:4px solid black;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:-10px;left:-10px;z-index:10;">
        </div>
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <!--Rest of the code stays same-->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I used inline-css here and it is working but be careful when you shift inline css to your stylesheet

Comment: Nice one, thank you Anuja. I've made those changes but they aren't working on the [live site](http://amalfi.madhatmedia.com.au/contact/). Can you help me diagnose what is wrong on the live site please?

Comment: I need to see more code. maybe you need to change original html a little bit. can you set up a fiddle.

Comment: I updated my answer. and I added some code that you need to put in your html file

Comment: Hi. The sidebar is generated by Wordpress, and I don't think these `div`s can be injected. Is there a pure CSS solution perhaps?

Comment: for a pure css, you need to have some html too. I am not that familier with wordpress so I cant help further but if by any way you could add those div in your html and transfer inline-style I added for them in our css. this solution will work 100%.

Comment: I was suspecting that the reason why @Steve didn't mark this answer as the solution was because the content inserted into `.container` wasn't displaying correctly. But then I tested and it was. Making `.inner` overlap it with `z-index` prevented its own background from hiding the content.

Answer (score -5):

you have given margin to section to -4%;
please change it to

```
.sidebar-primary section {
    margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;
}
```

i hope it'll help you